# OpenDDS Link Error when compiling nested Idl using MPC

Tags: visual-studio-code, idl, opendds

Trying to break up a large IDL definition file for the DDS Messages, and move some common types into another idl definition to make thing more manageable.

ERROR 1>FooTypesTypeSupportImpl.obj : error LNK2005: Java_foo_FooTypeTypeSupportImpl__1jni_1init already
defined in BarTypeTypeSupportImpl.obj

FooType.idl

```
 module foo {
  #pragma DCPS_DATA_TYPE "foo::FooType"  
  struct FooType {
    string publisherID;
    double timestampMs;
  };
```

};

BarTypes.idl

```
module bar {
  #pragma DCPS_DATA_TYPE "bar::TestMsg"  
  struct TestMsg {
    foo::FooType fooInfo;
    string key;
  };
```

};

BuildFooBar.mpc

```
project (FooBar): dcps_java {
  idlflags      += -Wb,stub_export_include=BarType_Export.h \
                   -Wb,stub_export_macro=BarType_Export
  dcps_ts_flags += -Wb,export_macro=BarType_Export
  idl2jniflags  += -Wb,stub_export_include=BarType_Export.h \
                   -Wb,stub_export_macro=BarType_Export
  dynamicflags  += BARTYPE_BUILD_DLL

  specific {
    jarname      = DDS_Test_Msg
  }

  TypeSupport_Files {
    BarType.idl
    FooTypes.idl
  }
}
```

BuildFooBar.bat

```
REM Changing Directory to Development FooBar
cd D:\dds\FooBar

REM Generating BarType_Export.h
"%ACE_ROOT%"\bin\generate_export_file.pl BarType > BarType_Export.h

REM Generating FooTypes_Export.h
"%ACE_ROOT%"\bin\generate_export_file.pl FooTypes > FooTypes_Export.h

REM Generating new VS Code Project
"%ACE_ROOT%"\bin\mwc.pl -type vs2019

REM Starting VS Code
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" FooBar.sln
```

Answer (score 0):

Further discussed on the [OpenDDS mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/opendds/mailman/opendds-main/thread/SN5P110MB0368CE31DB7426500E502F56A48B9%40SN5P110MB0368.NAMP110.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/#msg37218245)